# Display a dialog box whilst code runs

Tags: vb.net, dialog

I have the below code that opens a dialog box with messages of the progress to the user but the problem is the code wont run past displaying the dialog box as it is waiting for a result.  Is there any way around this?

```
    If VerifyDataInput() = True Then
        Dim dlg As New frmWorking
        dlg.lblMessage.Text = "Downloading Weather Data"
        dlg.ShowDialog()
        If GetWeather() = True Then
            dlg.lblMessage.Text = "Creating Weather Briefing"
            If CreateWeatherBriefing() = True Then
                Try
                    printWeatherBriefing.PrinterSettings = docWeatherBriefing.PrinterSettings
                    If printWeatherBriefing.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                        If printWeatherBriefing.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = strPrinterName Then
                            Dim strPrompt = "The selected printer is also your default RAW text printer." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
                                            "Would you like to print a RAW text only version?"
                            Dim result = MessageBox.Show(strPrompt, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button3)

                            If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                                Dim intExtraLines As Integer = 0
                                Do
                                    intExtraLines += 1
                                    strWXRawOutput &= Chr(10)
                                Loop Until intExtraLines = 6 + 1

                                RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(strPrinterName, strWXRawOutput, szDocName)
                            ElseIf result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
                                docWeatherBriefing.PrinterSettings = printWeatherBriefing.PrinterSettings
                                docWeatherBriefing.DocumentName = szDocName
                                docWeatherBriefing.Print()
                            End If
                        Else
                            docWeatherBriefing.PrinterSettings = printWeatherBriefing.PrinterSettings
                            docWeatherBriefing.DocumentName = szDocName
                            docWeatherBriefing.Print()
                        End If
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Dim strPrompt = "An error occurred when trying to print your weather briefing, please try again."
                    Dim blnErrorLogged = WriteToErrorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString, strPrompt, "Error")
                    MsgBox(strPrompt, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Me.Text)
                Finally
                    dlg.Dispose()
                End Try
            End If
        End If
        dlg.Dispose()
    End If
```

Comment: Of course it wont when you are asking them: **"If printWeatherBriefing.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then"**. You can't do that, it wont continue until the user does something with it... Another option is just create another class that you can call to show them the messages and such without requiring any input from user...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it very well.  It is the dlg at line 4.  I want that to display whilst the rest of the code still runs.

Comment: Try just `dlg.Show()`.  You are probably going to need a BackgroundWorker to do this right.

Comment: a status bar or label can display a message without blocking anything